# Custom Translator "Training Failed"

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

which is causing "training failed" from .doc or .txt files.

[image]

```
Training: 16,000    
Tuning: 14,000
Test: 13,500
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: 1) I have uploaded document contain two languages. 
 - Language (A)  and Language (B) .txt format
2) By using training model
3) The Result of Custom translator from Microsoft is resulted: “Training Failed”

Comment: please edit your question.. please include error messages you get (other than 'training failed')

Comment: In the custom translator has no log, please guide me where can I find error messages?

Answer (score 0):

If the training fails, it probably means that the number of sentences in the training set is too small.

Try to increase the number of sentences to meet the criteria stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/sentence-alignment) in order for the training to succeed!